# How can I stub out a global function called from a constructor?

Tags: ruby, rspec, rspec-mocks

I'm trying to stub out a global function called from a constructor. I'm using Rspec and Rspec-mocks. Here's the code to be tested:

```
def foo
  'foo'
end

class Bar
  def initialize
    @bar = foo
  end

  def bar
    @bar
  end
end
```

And here's the test:

```
describe 'bar'
  it 'calls foo' do
    expect(self).to receive(:foo) { 'bar' }

    expect(Bar.new.bar).to eq('bar')
  end
end
```

The test fails with the following message:

```
     Failure/Error: expect(Bar.new.bar).to eq('bar')

       expected: "bar"
            got: "foo"

       (compared using ==)
```

How can I stub out the global function`foo`?

PS: `expect(self).to receive(:foo) { 'bar' }` works as expected if `foo` is being called from another global function.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution is probably uses `#allow_any_instance_of`, which works because "global" functions are really `Kernel` methods in Ruby. But since [the documentation discourages](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/v/3-8/docs/working-with-legacy-code/any-instance) stubbing classes globally, I thought I'd at least offer an alternative:

```rb
def foo
  'foo'
end

class Bar
  def self.get_foo
    foo
  end

  def initialize
    @bar = self.class.get_foo
  end

  def bar
    @bar
  end
end
```

and

```rb
describe Bar do
  it 'gets foo' do
    expect(Bar).to receive(:get_foo).and_return('bar')

    expect(Bar.new.bar).to eq('bar')
  end
end
```

Of course, if possible, it would better to ditch the `Kernel` method and just use the class method.

Answer (score 0):

```
allow_any_instance_of(Bar).to receive(:foo) { 'bar' }
```